# How to find how many methods and their names used my variable in a java program?

Tags: java

Here is example to find how many variables used in my class. But I need to find how many methods are using my variable with in a class.

Test class having four methods but sample1 variable is used in test1() and test3() methods. **I want output as test1(),test2() are used sample1 variable**

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class Test {

private int sample1;
private int sample2;
private int sample3;

public void test1()
{
    System.out.println(sample1);
}
public void test2()
{
    System.out.println(sample2);
}
public void test3()
{
    System.out.println(sample1);
}
public void test4()
{
    System.out.println(sample3);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Test t = new Test();

    Field f[] =Test.class.getDeclaredFields();
    for (int i = 0; i < f.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Variable Name is : " + f[i].getName());
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I do not think you will be able to do this with class reflection methods. You would have to decompile the java class bytecode to be able to scan what variables, etc a method is using.

Comment: BTW your example code shows the "fields" "declared" in your class not "variables" "used" in your class. It's all in the terminology and in the name of the method you  chose to use to get the field details :D

Comment: You can do it using AspectJ with load time weaving (no change to existing code). But this adds complexity, performance issues and aspectj (steep-learning curve).

Answer (score 0):

Can this help?

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    private int sample1;
    private int sample2;
    private int sample3;
    private ArrayList<String> whoUseSameple1= new ArrayList<String>();

    int getSample1(String methodname){
        whoUseSameple1.add(methodname);
        return sample1;
    }
    public void test1(){
        System.out.println(getSample1(new Object(){}.getClass().getEnclosingMethod().getName()));
    }
    public void test2(){
        System.out.println(sample2);
    }
    public void test3(){
        System.out.println(getSample1(new Object(){}.getClass().getEnclosingMethod().getName()));
    }
    public void test4(){
        System.out.println(sample3);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Main t = new Main();
        t.test1();
        t.test2();
        t.test3();
        t.test4();


        for (String s:t.whoUseSameple1){
            System.out.print(s+" ");
        }
        System.out.print("are usd Sample1 Variable\n");
    // Field f[] =Main.class.getDeclaredFields();
    // for (int i = 0; i < f.length; i++)
    // {
        // System.out.println("Variable Name is : " + f[i].getName());
    // }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Hui, Thank you for your solution but i need the information regarding each variable with out  changing any code in my methods (test1,test2,test3,test4).In our class having nearly 1000 variables and more than 1000 methods is their in that situation what can i do? please share me any method in Reflection API or any suitable solution for this. Thank you Hui for your solution.

Comment: You have a singular class that contains 1,000 fields and 1,000 methods? Dam. Not sure why you are doing this excercise but if you do not have to provide a code solution, just provide call graphs for a proposed refactoring then you might be able to get way with porting the class to something like eclipse and use the ide features for call graphing, if not then sorry but this seems a momumentous task for soemone that i snot steeped in reflection, et al.